# SQLAlchemy cursor approach with pagination

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy as an ORM for my MySql backend database. I have 2 tables that needs to be joined together but these tables have more than 550k records individually. I join them and paginate using the below code -

```
result = session.query(Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2, Table1.Col3, ...
                       Table2.Col1, Table2.Col2, Table2.Col3, ...
                .select_from(join(Table1, Table2, (Table1.Col1== Table2.Col1)
                              & (Table1.Col2== Table2.Col2))) \
                .filter(Table1.someCol == some_value) \
                .order_by(Table1.Col2.asc())

# code for pagination - This allows me to use paginate function of Flask-SqlAlchemy from a SQLAlchemy query object 
# by directly passing in result object above
def paginate(query, page, per_page=20, error_out=True):
    query.__class__ = BaseQuery
    return query.paginate(page, per_page, error_out)
```

Then, finally I use render_template and pass in the paginated object for rendering html content.

The problem here is that this approach is slow and memory intensive. The join query here brings the entire result set into memory and then paginates it. Moreover, Flask-SQLAlchemy's pagination under the hood uses limit and offset which become slow for huge datasets.

For solving this, I can across cursor based pagination approach but I am unable to find a cursor based solution which iterates the joined resultset in chunks and can also be used with flask's render_template for rending content at the front end.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
table1:  INDEX(someCol, col2)
table2:  INDEX(col1, col2)
```

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the generated SQL for the `SELECT`.

Pagination:  "Remember where you left off instead of using the much slower `OFFSET`.

Comment: By generated SQL query, do you mean raw sql join query generated by flask?

Comment: @ashwanikumar - Yes.  It will probably begin with `SELECT`.